# Rails association for post and location - has_many and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, associations

I am creating a `Post` model which has one `Location`. A `Location` can be in many `Post`s. For this relationship, I created the field `location_id` in `Post`.

I was wondering to do the following belongs_to and has_many:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :description, :price, :location_id
   belongs_to :location
end


class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :latitude, :longitude, :name
   has_many :posts
end
```

Creating these two models, when I know that I can create a post doing something like:

```
my_post = my_location.posts.create ....
```

but in my application, people will search about Post description, and in the results it need to show all Post that were found and the name of the Location, like:

```
Post Description: XXXXXXX
Location Name: New York

Post Description: YYYYYYY
Location Name: New York

Post Description: ZZZZZZ
Location Name: Chicago
```

What is the best way to do this association. As I'm doing, in my Post in only have my location_id and I cant do something like (i got a method missing error)

```
my_post.location.name
```

I don't think I'm doing right If I need to search for each my_post.location_id, just to get the location name.

This in fact was some stupid mistake that I really don't know what I did, sorry, and thanks for the help

Comment: `my_post.location.name` should work.  What _exactly_ is the "method missing error"? If it's "no method `name` for Nil" then you have a different issue, which means that your post has no assigned location record.

Comment: Fernando, if you discovered this was just a mistake please update your question and select the most helpful answer so this question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the error message that you are getting?

```
my_post.location.name
```

should work, as far as my_post has an associated Location

Comment: I really don't know what stupid thing that I did, but after your answer I tried it in the rails console and now Its working... I'm really sorry and I dont what stupid thing I did that it was not working before.... Thanks a lot....